# How do I used a database I created in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 with a VS C# Project?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I created a new database using SQL Server 2008 R2 by using the Management Studio. The connection says (local) and I am using Windows Authentication (though I installed with mixed mode).

My questions are:

1. How do I connect to the DB via my C# application -

   The only time I ever have done this before I just used VS Menu > Tools > Connect to DB and the drop down saw my database and connected, then right clicked on it and grabbed the connection string for use in connecting. However I'm thinking because its (local) I don't have that option.
2. As per Q#1 I am assuming the database file is being stored somewhere locally - I am wondering how to find that location and how I can include it with my application

Edit** Per comment: VSMenu-> View-> Server Explorer and then use add connection to connect to your local SQL Server instance and then use the database you created from the databases dropdown, and from advance settings copy the connection string created by the connection dialog

This is what I am looking for but I am missing the step during "add connection" where do I find my SQL Server I created locally? As mentioned before I have no idea where it is stored or how to find it

Comment: The most basic way to connect to a database from a .net application is to use ADO.NET http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090.aspx

Comment: Not sure if this helps but you can goto `VSMenu-> View-> Server Explorer` and then use add connection to connect to your local SQL Server instance and then use the database you created from the databases dropdown, and from advance settings copy the connection string created by the connection dialog.

Comment: @Nilesh This is exactly what I am looking for - however, when I go to add connection I have no idea how to find my local connection... as I mentioned before I have only worked when someone else has created an actual server and I created a (local) server so I have no idea how to find it from the add connection option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has an example in the SQLConnection documentation

```
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

You can then optionally use a SqlDataAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ADO.NET, which is comprised of a connection object (`SqlConnection`), command object (`SqlCommand`), parameters objects (`SqlParameter`) and data sets (`DataSet`) or data readers (`SqlDataReader`).

Read [A Beginner's Tutorial for Understanding ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET).

Comment: I should extend my question to indicate I understand the basics that your link is showing, but I have only ever connected to an existing Database server per my original comments, I have never created one of my own like I have now - so my issue is figuring out how to connect to the one I created

Comment: Nothing wrong with Entity Framework, just think that understanding ADO.NET is a good idea and then once you have that understanding then using an ORM in certain instances makes sense and possibly micro-ORM in others. I think it is like learning to program ASP.NET by writing the HTML by hand as opposed to learning by using the drag and drop designer, you learn more by writing the plumbing instead of learning by using a tool that abstracts away a lot of that.

Comment: Not everyone learns the same. At first I didn't get `ADO`, but totally got `EF`. Now I could use either.